# Are infants and small children really manifestation of Bramhan

Tags: scripture, life

There is a saying in hindi

> Bacche bhagwan ka roop hote hai

literally meaning

> Kids are incarnation or manifestation of Bramhan.

Since Bhagwan is used to refer Bramahan or the Ishta devta (for Smartha people).
So this means that it is just a saying derived from the happy and blissful nature of kids(since bramhan is Sat-chit-Ananda) or it has a scriptural basis?.

Comment: I think Skanda Purana says that  Karma will be applied only for deeds done after age of 8. So, people below 8 have no karma and they generally have ignorance and innocence. So, may be due to this they are called as manifestation of Brahman.